# Method Marked @Async stop executing at Map Object operations Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, executorservice

I have a method that sends email notifications to users asynchronously, the method calls a method below that creates a map object containing mail parameters to be passed to the send mail method

```
@Override
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<Void> sendNotification(AppUser appUser) {

        log.info("In the send notification method --> {},  request-->{}", appUser, request);
//        eventPublisher.publishEvent(new OnRegistrationCompleteEvent(appUser,
//                request.getLocale(), getBaseUrl()));

        confirmRegistration(appUser, "hsfksdfjkhkjshsfkjhkj");

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);

    }
```

During execution the above method enters the ***confirmRegistration*** method and executes till it gets to the point where I am creating a map and adding properties to the map, a that point the Executor service shuts down.

Withing the method, it calls another method that creates a map object and adds the email properties

```
   private void confirmRegistration(AppUser user, String token) {
//        String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        log.info("Creating verification token ---> {}", token);
//        advertiserService.createVerificationToken(user, token);

        Map<String, String> params = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        params.put("recipientAddress", user.getEmail());
        params.put("subject", "Registration Confirmation");
        params.put("text", getBaseUrl() + "/regitrationConfirm.html?token=" + token);

        log.info("Calling sendMessage method with params --> ");
        sendMessage(new ConcurrentHashMap<>(), Locale.getDefault());

    }
```

Here is the test execution log, the log show that the executorService shut down after getting to the point where I create a map and perform the add operation, the log shows this.

```
2021-04-29 16:50:23.060  INFO 41927 --- [           main] c.p.y.service.mail.EmailServiceImplTest  : Starting EmailServiceImplTest using Java 11.0.10 on oluwatobi-Latitude-E5450 with PID 41927 (started by oluwatobi in /home/oluwatobi/dev/ycBackend-Monolitic-2)
2021-04-29 16:50:23.062  INFO 41927 --- [           main] c.p.y.service.mail.EmailServiceImplTest  : The following profiles are active: dev
2021-04-29 16:50:24.184  INFO 41927 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-04-29 16:50:24.524  INFO 41927 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 331 ms. Found 9 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-04-29 16:50:25.318  INFO 41927 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-04-29 16:50:25.369  INFO 41927 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
2021-04-29 16:50:25.502  INFO 41927 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-04-29 16:50:25.628  INFO 41927 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-04-29 16:50:25.938  INFO 41927 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-04-29 16:50:25.964  INFO 41927 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2021-04-29 16:50:26.822  INFO 41927 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator     : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.project.yconnector.model.user.VerificationToken (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2021-04-29 16:50:27.207  INFO 41927 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-04-29 16:50:27.216  INFO 41927 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-29 16:50:27.313  WARN 41927 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-04-29 16:50:28.538  INFO 41927 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@d695f9d, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@76efa2b7, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3c2e73ce, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@7daf167, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2ca464bb, com.project.yconnector.security.JWTAuthenticationFilter@5d3a238, com.project.yconnector.security.JWTAuthorizationFilter@6df4d8f1, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@64b20d9c, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@41041c31, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@735b1ad2, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7925e772, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@58a0f75b, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1188e08b]
2021-04-29 16:50:28.568  INFO 41927 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'getAsyncExecutor'
2021-04-29 16:50:29.714  INFO 41927 --- [           main] c.p.y.service.mail.EmailServiceImplTest  : Started EmailServiceImplTest in 7.232 seconds (JVM running for 9.135)
2021-04-29 16:50:29.832  INFO 41927 --- [AsyncExecutor-1] c.p.y.service.mail.EmailServiceImpl      : In the send notification method --> AppUser(id=null, email=t.com, password=null, roles=null, isVerified=true),  request-->null
2021-04-29 16:50:29.849  INFO 41927 --- [AsyncExecutor-1] c.p.y.service.mail.EmailServiceImpl      : Creating verification token ---> hsfksdfjkhkjshsfkjhkj
2021-04-29 16:50:29.873  INFO 41927 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'getAsyncExecutor'
2021-04-29 16:50:29.879  INFO 41927 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-29 16:50:29.881  INFO 41927 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-04-29 16:50:29.902  INFO 41927 --- [extShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: By the log output, seems more like the app is stopping and the application context releases resources and stops.

Comment: If you are in test context and your test method has finished execution then the jvm will not wait for the the async method to finish which will be running in separate thread.

Comment: Yes I  was in the test context, but I called the async method directly from the test context, so I expect that it executes all the actions within....

Comment: When I removed the map declaration, it completed execution, but when I added it, it stopped executing

Comment: That is a race condition. Setu is right, the test does not wait for the async thread to finish, you have to do it yourself. You could use a library like `Awaitility`.